# Can someone explain why this input code generates the provided output?

Tags: c++, scope

I need help understanding the function of the curly brackets in the C++ code below. Looking at it, it seems it initializes variables locally within the statement in the curly brackets, thus not influencing any of the global variably in the main function. What I am trying to understand is why. My textbook is not clear on this.

**Input:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    {
        int x = 13;
        cout << x << ",";
    }
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Ouput**:

13,0

Comment: What textbook are you using? You might search the index for the term "scope".

Comment: another keyword to investigate is "shadowing".

Comment: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope)

Comment: @Cornelius Mynhardt  Read at last at least  one book on C++ for beginners.

Comment: If you put a picture on top of another picture and then take it off, you are not surprised to see the first picture again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observations are correct.

New variables declared in a deeper brackets are separate from already-existing variables at outer brackets/etc and 'shadow' them - from inside the deeper brackets you will have a hard time getting to the outer `x` from outer brackets, because any attempt to write "x" will mean the x-from-deeper-brackets, until as the deeper-brackets end. After deeper-brackets end, "x" will again mean the-x-from-outer-brackets.

Now, as one of the commenters said, the notion of "deeper/outer brackets that shadow things from outer brackets" is formally called "scope". We talk about outer scopes, inner/deeper scopes. So, there's a global scope (all the loosely-floating things outside of anything - i.e. `using namespace std` is in the global scope), the scope of `main` function (it's body delimited by `{..}`), scope of `for` loop, scope of `if` body, and so on.

Having scopes that hide/shadow things from over scopes, is a quite important thing to get used to, as it related to several things like:

- controlling variables you can access (like in your example: outer x vs deeper x)
- when objects are destroyed (like: the inner `x` may actually be destroyed when inner `}` ends)

and those two relatively simple concepts (maybe even sounding unimportant), actually open up ways for several further techniques and possibilities which are used very extensively in almost any C++ program.

..well.. maybe the latter one, the 'destruction at end of scope'.. this is really important thing to rememeber.

The first one, the 'shadowing', is sometimes even considered a bit 'evil' as it requires you to be constantly aware if it's still your X, or outer X already, or maybe X from global scope.. when writing a program, you often pick names that doesn't clash, just to NOT have to think and track that. But it's needed. Without it you'd quickly run out of popular variable names. You'd be surprised how many variable/function/class names can be already taken when you #include several libraries :)

As for the main question `What I am trying to understand is why.` the answer can be only one: because the language has been designed like that. It's handy.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation and quick response on the question. Really helps to clear up the understanding. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The curly braces you have after `int x = 0;` define a new scope, as mentioned in the comments.
Inside of this scope you are defining a NEW x variable. (Rather than referencing the old one, `x = 13`, without the type name)

Once this scope exits, right after printing 13, every thing inside of it doesn't matter anymore as it's not "in-scope". It basically gets deleted.
That means afterwards `x` is back  to the original value of `0`.